# Using Eclipselink with Streams gives NullPointerException

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

we have an application that uses Eclipselink weaving with JPA. Let's say we have a Family object that has a one to many relationship with a Person object. We retrieve a set of Person objects from the database and then use Java 8 Streams and a spliterator to process the Person objects in parallel. We end up getting a NullPointerException which from poking around in the Eclipselink code appears to have been caused by two threads operating on different Person objects but trying to instantiate the same Family clone object at the same time.

It appears from googling that Eclipselink using weaving and lazy loading in this manner is not thread safe, is that correct? If so, what's the best way of handling this whilst still retaining some degree of parallelisation?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear from the description - are you reading a single Person instance and then sharing that among different threads?

Objects read from a single EntityManager are not thread safe - they are managed and tracked by that EntityManager, which is meant to represent a single process' unit of work. Every thread needs to read the objects from their own EntityManager; this is configured to make copies of entities from the shared cache. Otherwise, if you need to cache an object for use among different threads, you can make sure the entire graph is fetched or add synchronization on lazily fetched parts yourself.

Comment: We have Thread A accessing Person A and Thread B accessing Person B. Both Person A and Person B point to the same Family F. The problem is that the getFamily logic that is responsible for instantiating the common Family object is implemented by the eclipselink persistence weaving code. It is not something we have control over. We will take your advice to prefetch, thanks.